# Cookie empty/not set on requests via next.js API proxy after storing it

Tags: cookies, next.js, jwt, next.js13

When I send a request via a tool (e.g. Insomnia), the cookie is present. If I try to fetch data in the next.js application (SSR), the cookie is undefined.

How I store the cookie (in `/pages/api/auth.ts`):

```js
      const cookies = new Cookies(request, response);
      cookies.set("mhg-token", data.token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
        sameSite: "lax",
      });
```

How I read use the cookie (in `/pages/api/[...path].ts`):

```js
    const cookies = new Cookies(request, response);
    const authToken = cookies.get("mhg-token");

    console.log(authToken);
```

This requests are working:

1. Request: POST `/api/auth` with login data as json body to store the JWT token in a cookie.
2. Resest: GET `/api/me` to fetch the data of the current user. The backend API endpoint requires a authentication with a JWT.

The first request works also in the next.js application without any error and in the dev-tools I can see that a cookie is created. But if I try to fetch data in the app (such as `/api/me`) the cookie is `undefined`.

This is the code full code of `/pages/api/[...path].ts`:

```js
import Cookies from "cookies";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import getConfig from "next/config";

const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
const { backendApiUrl } = serverRuntimeConfig;
const APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";

export default async function handler(
  request: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  const url = request.url?.replace("/api/", "");
  const method = request.method;
  console.log(`Request ${method} ${request.url}`);
  try {
    const body = request.body;

    const cookies = new Cookies(request, response);
    const authToken = cookies.get("mhg-token");

    console.log(authToken);

    const headers: HeadersInit = {
      accept: APPLICATION_JSON,
      "Content-Type": APPLICATION_JSON,
    };

    if (authToken !== undefined) {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;
    }

    const parameters: RequestInit = {
      method: method ?? "GET",
      headers: headers,
    };

    if (method === "POST" || method === "PUT") {
      parameters.body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }

    const serviceResponse = await fetch(`${backendApiUrl}/${url}`, parameters);

    const data = await serviceResponse.json();

    console.log(`Response: Status ${serviceResponse.status}`);

    if (serviceResponse.status !== 200) {
      console.log(data);
    }

    response.status(serviceResponse.status).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
}
```